# How to detect all strings with a character except for those with some condition in regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to detect and replace all the '%' inside an html string with their ascii code but not replace the ones where the '%' is inside an `<a>` tag. I can't figure out how to write the regex for it.

```
the test is
<a href="%aci%">find</a>

%asd%
```

So far, I got something like this: https://regex101.com/r/IwcebN/1

But it doesn't detect the '%' at the bottom...regex

Comment: Off topic, but your href contains an error. Or, if this is a UTF-8 environment, two.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Try this:

```
(%)(?![^<]*?>)
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/IwcebN/4)

### Edit (updated explanation):

Wherever it finds % sign it immediately looks ahead of it for > sign. But, while looking for it this [^<] ensures that < doesn't come before >. If < is found after  a % then it doesn't look for > anymore. And marks % as the positive match.

Things to be noted that, as javascript doesn't support lookbehind therefore you will have to apply some programming tricks to do it in other way. Moreover most of the languages don't support look behind of variable length. As a result from % you can see if it contains > sign ahead but won't be able to look for < using look behind of variable length. So in case any % sign of this following pattern won't be captured :

```
safdasdfasf % >
```

Comment: Tried it on jquery, it is working nicely for my requirements. Thanks!

Comment: I am however having some problems understanding it.....It is matching the strings where there is '%' and NOT having '<' immeditately after it? Can u please explain?